# present or future with "whichever ... sooner"?

Tags: tenses

Recently I was writing a formal letter to governmental bodies for some request. And one of the sentences was this:

> I will leave the State by the time of expiration of my permission or my intended return date, whichever ... sooner.

I used **whichever is sooner**, but I was not completely sure, and am not now. The problem is at the time of writing I did not know the exact time/date when my permission would expire, that is why it seemed that **whichever will be sooner** was correct. I need to know for sure which version I should use next time in a similar situation.

Thanks

Comment: Why not sooner? Also, could you please elaborate more on the usage of present tense? If one of the dates is not defined, how can we say `is`? To me it sounds similar to `Believe me, when I finish building my house, it is nicer than yours`. How is this one different from `whichever is earlier`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One frequent way of phrasing this is *whichever occurs first*.

(The "present tense" is often used to indicate a future action; even the present continuous, like "I'm going to the shops tomorrow.")

The rest of the sentence is very wordy, which may have contributed to your misgivings. If you're discussing dates, you don't need *by the time of,* for example.

> I will leave the State either before my permission expires, or before my intended return date, whichever occurs first.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, I like your version, but you still did not answer my question. Do you mean that `whichever is/will be sooner` is completely wrong?

Comment: If you really want to use that, then use ***is***, not *will be*.

Comment: I have already used `is`. Can you explain why not `will be`? (Please see my comment to original question to understand my point)

Answer (score 1):

The tense of "whichever is sooner" is fine.  You may not know offhand which date will occur first, but that both dates will occur is a present-tense fact and, if one does precede the other, whichever date is earlier is also a present-tense fact.

This is different than the "will be" of "When I finish building my house, it will be nicer than yours."  The house itself and its eventual condition are not present-tense facts.  On the other hand, it's similar to the "finish".  That the house will someday be finished is a present-tense fact.  You don't say "when I will finish".

English grammar doesn't have an explicit conditional mode.  Your choice is between the indicative "whichever is sooner" and the subjunctive "whichever be sooner".  The subjunctive mode sees very little use in contemporary dialects, and I won't recommend its use in this case.

Think of it this way:  Dates on a calendar already exist today.  The intention to build the house already exists today.  The verbs attached to those ideas are present-tense verbs.  Your act of leaving the State hasn't happened yet.  The house doesn't exist yet.  The verbs attached to those ideas are future-tense verbs.  You've placed the future actions in the future tense, and you've place the conditional clauses in the present tense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good reason. And no, it doesn't seem to make sense. But Andrew is right; we would not use the future tense in that particular construction. Call it a quirk of habit.  "whichever is first" , "whichever occurs sooner", "whichever comes first"... but NOT "whichever will be [first/sooner[".

You will be often frustrated if you demand consistency from English usage patterns. There are rules, and there are exceptions. If you learn enough rules, you find fewer exceptions—but always some.